# Leaving a <object> window when clicking on a link

Tags: html, object

I have an `<object>` which shows a table from an external website. The problem is that when you click on a link in the table, the site opens in the `<object>` window.

Is it possible that I click on a link, and the site opens normally and not in the `<object>` window?

Answer (score 0):

No.

It would require that the page in the frame set the link targets to `_top` or `_parent`. By default a link will open in the same frame.

Assuming you don't control the page loaded into the frame, you have no way of changing the link target (and the same origin policy prevents you changing it with JS).